# How to combine the results returned by Multicast Delegates in C#?

Tags: c#, delegates

I want to combine the results returned by the two function calls through the invocation of a multicast delegate. But I keep getting an exception saying that del is a variable but is used like a method.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MultiDelegateConsoleApplication
{
    public delegate void SampleMultiDelegate(string args,out string SampleString);

    class Program
    {
        public static void SayHello(string args,out string s1)
        {
            s1 = "Hello " + args;
        }
        public static void SayGoodbye(string args,out string s2)
        {
            s2 = "Goodbye " + args;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SampleMultiDelegate sampleMultiDelegate = new SampleMultiDelegate(SayHello);
            sampleMultiDelegate += SayGoodbye;
            string param1 = "Chiranjib";
            string param2,param3;
            Console.WriteLine("**************Individual Function Invoke***********");
            SayHello(param1,out param2);
            SayGoodbye(param1, out param3);
            Console.WriteLine("**************Multicast Delegate Invoke***********");
            sampleMultiDelegate(param1,out param2);
            Console.WriteLine(param2); //The multicast delegate will always return the result of the last function
            string result;
            foreach (Delegate del in sampleMultiDelegate.GetInvocationList())
            {
                result = del(param1,out param2);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Could you please explain and help me fix the error?

Comment: Why are you expecting `del` to return a value when the delegate return type is `void`?

Comment: 1. Not `Delegate del` but `SampleMultiDelegate del`

2. `SampleMultiDelegate` returns `void`, so you just write `del(param1, out param2);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to cast each function in the invocation list to the delegate type to be able to use the normal function call syntax :

```
void Main()
{
    var sampleMultiDelegate = new SampleMultiDelegate(SayHello);
    sampleMultiDelegate += SayGoodbye;
    var param1 = "Chiranjib";
    string param2;
    string result = "";
    foreach (var del in sampleMultiDelegate.GetInvocationList())
    {
        var f = (SampleMultiDelegate)del;
        f(param1, out param2);
        result += param2 + "\r\n";
    }

    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Also fixed the fact that there can't be any result to your delegate calls as they return `void`.

Comment: Thanks for the help :) Works great !

Answer (score 1):

This code works to get each result. The key is my `unfurl` function that changes the return type.

```
SampleMultiDelegate sampleMultiDelegate = new SampleMultiDelegate(SayHello);
sampleMultiDelegate += SayGoodbye;

string param1 = "Chiranjib";

Func<SampleMultiDelegate, string, string> unfurl =
    (d, p1) =>
    {
        string r;
        d(p1, out r);
        return r;
    };

string result =
    String.Join(
        Environment.NewLine,
        sampleMultiDelegate
            .GetInvocationList()
            .Cast<SampleMultiDelegate>()
            .Select(d => unfurl(d, param1)));

Console.WriteLine(result);
```